# How to rewrite code with then to await version

Tags: dart

I wrote code

```
pendingFutures.addAll({sqlQuery.hashCode: connection.query(sqlQuery, timeoutInSeconds: 3600)});
var queryResult = await pendingFutures[sqlQuery.hashCode]; 
var queryObj = RequestCacheStruct(sqlQuery.hashCode, DateTime.now(), queryResult! );
await pendingFutures.remove(sqlQuery.hashCode); 
requestsCacheList.add(queryObj);
```

But it's seems that code above have different behavior than code below:

```
pendingFutures[sqlQuery.hashCode] =
      connection.query(...)
          .then((queryResult) {
              // TODO: add queryResult into cache.
          });
  await pendingFutures[sqlQuery.hashCode];
```

How to fix first code to make it work as second one?

My friend who wrote second code said:
"In the first case, await `pendingFutures[...]` will return as soon as the request is finished.

In the second - when the request is finished and the record is added to the cache."

Comment: The second version looks like it should behave like the first (although since you've omitted details in the second, I can't say if you're actually doing the same things).  Could you elaborate on what you're differences you're observing?

Comment: @jamesdlin I have add mention about what I am expecting about code.

Comment: Er, so did you actually observe different behaviors, or are you basing it entirely on what your friend told you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to distill your examples down so that they're proper apples-to-apples comparisons.  Given:

```dart
theFuture = someAsyncOperation();
var result = await theFuture;
addToCache(result);
additionalWork();
```

and

```dart
theFuture = someAsyncOperation().then((result) => addToCache(result));
await theFuture;
additionalWork();
```

where `theFuture` is some non-local variable, then those `await theFuture;` lines should not result in any material difference: `addToCache` will be called before `additionalWork`.

However, a more interesting question (and probably what your friend meant) is that if `theFuture` is *separately* `await`ed:

```dart
await theFuture;
yetMoreWork();
```

will it be guaranteed that `yetMoreWork` is called after `addToCache`?  In other words: if two `.then()` callbacks are registered on the same `Future`, are the callbacks guaranteed to be fired in order of registration? (From what I've observed, it seems that way, but I don't know if it's necessarily true, or even if it is, if it will be guaranteed to be true in the future.)

Back to your original question: how can you rewrite the first form to use only `await` but still guarantee that operations are serialized in a well-defined manner?  You have to create a `Future` that completes after `addToCache` is called, and you can do that with a helper function:

```dart
Future<void> helperFunction() async {
  var result = await someAsyncOperation();
  addToCache(result);
}

theFuture = await helperFunction();
additionalWork();
```